# Sample Code with Examples for the C++ Google Style Guide?

Tags: c++, google-style-guide

Are there any good places to get examples for the C++ Google Style Guide?

Comment: Do you plan to work at Google?

Comment: Nope.  The company I work for told me that these are pretty close to the standards that we're going to use for writing C++ code.

Comment: FWIW, the Google C++ guides are not necessarily good for anybody else.  They were designed for Google's purposes and situations.  Just because Google is a highly successful high-tech company doesn't mean that what's good for it is good for everybody.

Comment: I pity you, C with Objects is certainly not a language I wish to work with.

Comment: @David Please tell this to my superiors. I have no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google open sources a number of projects, most of which comply with their [style guides](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/):

- [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)
- [re2 - pcre regular expressions](http://code.google.com/p/re2/)
- [perf tools - multithreaded performance analysis tools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/)
- [gflags - command line flags](http://code.google.com/p/google-gflags/)

Search Google code for google projects, and you'll find a lot!

Comment: gflags is a mess regarding variable names -- snake and camel mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/coding-style
http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/

The source code for Chrome should theoretically follow their standards :)

Comment: From the first page: `Chromium follows the Google C++ Style Guide unless an exception is listed below.`. So Chromium does not entirely follow the Google Style, therefore it's probably not the best reference code.